# How can I use the SQLite SUM() function?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

*

### My problem

Recently, I ran some of my Java code  [Open Helper] through android studio , and it gave the following error :
**I have an login page with android (java code) and just my problem when time that must be password just string put , will be true. but if was put numerical password , will not true .**

    code SqlOpenHelper

```
package com.example.root.sql2;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
public class db extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public db(Context context) {
        super(context, "login.db", null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USER(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,NAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
    public boolean insert (String name , String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("NAME", name);
        contentValues.put("PASSWORD", password);
        long ins = db.insert("USER","",contentValues);
        if (ins == -1) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    public boolean login(String name , String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME=? AND PASSWORD=?", new String[] {name , password});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

> "password" if was string ,password then is true but "password" if was string ,password(numerical) then will not true ...
>   
>   *

Comment: what exactly are you doing or trying to achieve? numerical passwords instead of strings?

Comment: It's not clear how the SQL SUM() function has a role in that.

Comment: My problem is that I enter the information using the function INSERT  and check the information with the function LOGIN for the entry operation  but l dont know  for why, when i using password of number type(for example 1996) , function LOGIN ,give me return is   false .

however and when i using password  string type (for example root) function LOGIN ,give return is   true.

summry , i can NOT  using password or username type of number .

Comment: i can NOT  using password or username, type of number .

Comment: Given that all passwords should be **strings** (alphanumeric, alphabetic in mixed case and numeric characters all in one password), why in the world would you ever want to **SUM()** your passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your main issue is that your logic is reversed.

You are basically saying by  using `if (cursor.getCount()>0) return false;`; if the search for the user found the user then return false.

I believe you want `if (cursor.getCount()>0) return true;`

However, albeit it not an issue, the use of **moveToFirst** adds nothing of use. Additionally you may encounter issues because you are not closing the cursor.

I'd suggest that you perhaps use :-

```
public boolean login(String name , String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME=? AND PASSWORD=?", new String[] {name , password});
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return count > 0;
}
```

- This gets the count, closes the cursor, then returns true if the count is greater than 0 (user password combination was found) otherwise false;